# can not read the docx file python-docx 0.5.0

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I want to read a docx file with python3.3 and python-docx 0.5.0

I read a docx documentation, but I cant find how read the file, only how open...

Please give an example how read a docx file with python-docx 0.5.0

Comment: What do you mean by "reading" a docx file? You want content as str? Or do you just want to load document into memory?

Comment: i want learn both options, can you give an examples

Comment: Man, you didn't even try. https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/documents.html - example of loading document into memory. I assumed that reading content as str may not be trivial, bvut it should be somewhere there, on their doc page.

Answer (score 1):

You can view (text) the content of the document by the following code.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document(file_path)
text = []
for data in document.paragraphs:
    text.append(data.text)
    print(data.text)
```